# Assign ID to an asp.net Javascript button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my code I have a button for entering data, but as shown in the image below it only reads the first line independent of the button.

[image: img]

I believe this is because the button id is not being assigned to each row.

How can I get my id from each row to my button?

My ID is ID_Info

```
 <td>
     <button class="btn ToEditbtn" ><span class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></span>Edit</button>
     <button class="btn Editbtn" style="display:none"><span class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true">Save</span></button>

 </td>

@section scripts{
<script>

    $(function () {
        $("#ordertable").on("click", ".ToEditbtn", function () {
            $(this).hide();
            var currenttr = $(this).closest("tr");
            currenttr.find(".Editbtn").show();
            currenttr.find(".Status").prop("disabled", false);
            currenttr.find(".Obs").prop("disabled", false);
        });
        //update
        $("#ordertable").on("click", ".Editbtn", function () {
                var status = new Object();
                status.ID_Info = $(".ID_Info").val();
                status.Status = $(".Status").val();
                status.Obs = $(".Obs").val();

         ...

         <script>
         }
```

Thanks

Comment: This might help, its the same issue and solution worked for him. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65731975/data-not-insert-and-update-through-ajax-and-jquery-in-admin-page/65733177#65733177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on `save` button you are getting values using `$(".ID_Info")` this will not give you required value because there are mutliple class with same name . So, to target only required values you can use `$(this).closest('tr').find('valueyouneedtofind')..` i.e:

```
$("#ordertable").on("click", ".Editbtn", function() {
  var status = new Object();
  status.ID_Info = $(this).closest('tr').find(".ID_Info").val();
  status.Status = $(this).closest('tr').find(".Status").val();
  status.Obs = $(this).closest('tr').find(".Obs").val();
  //other codes
})
```

Comment: that's right, thanks, by the way since i'm receiving the data can you help me save? because I use db.savechanges but it doesn't record

Comment: Hi , i would helped but , i have limited knowledge in asp :)